# Join repeats records?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3

I have tables in the database that are related. The (RT) has four lines that relate to the other four lines (t.b) The query is realized by means of a (user.id) that exists in both tables.

The problem happens in the query return that repeats over 12 lines? How can I deal with this error? Below is the code and link:

```
  public function planstypes_head($elev_opename_id) {
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('elev_plans_types');
$this->db->join('elev_share_plans', 'elev_share_plans.elev_opename_id = elev_plans_types.elev_opename_id' , 'left');
$this->db->where('elev_plans_types.elev_opename_id', $elev_opename_id);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result(); }
```

[Follows the layout of the tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lSYv.png)

Comment: we really need to see your schema, sample data and output that you consider erroneous.

Comment: link: http://elevsaude.webstrucs.com/tabelas/elevsaude/operadora/1

Comment: Yes it will come like that because you don't have a unique column id something like auto_increment column. If you create that then it shows a result as four entry as a output... Hope you understand... If you need more help on it... Im happy top guide you through